# ObjectDisposedException When using MD5 ComputeHash

Tags: c#, hash, cryptography, md5, cryptographic-hash-function

I am getting ObjectDisposedException: Safe handle has been closed.

This is my code:

I am trying to create an interface and implementing class that will enable me to get a string, attach to it a known key, compute MD5 hash for this string and the key, and return the computed hash:

```
public interface ISignService
{
    string GetSignature(string str);
}

public class SignService : ISignService
{
    private readonly ISignSettings _signSettings;
    private readonly HashAlgorithm _hashAlgo;


    public SignService(ISignSettings signSettings)
    {
        _signSettings = signSettings;
        _hashAlgo = MD5.Create();
    }

    public string GetSignature(string str)
    {
        var strWithKey = str + _signSettings.EncryptionKey;

        var hashed = _hashAlgo.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strWithKey));

        return hashed.ToHexString();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Which line of code throws the exception?

Comment: Is `hashed.ToHexString()` an extension method? I pasted your code and the method doesn't exist...

Comment: Hi, it is an extension method. the line that throws is:         var hashed = _hashAlgo.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strWithKey));

Comment: Your code works. The problem should be somewhere outside of what you've shown to us. Probable, `_hashAlgo` gets disposed somtime...

Comment: This is almost definitely a multi-threading issue, which will cause exactly this exception. See the answer to [Finalizer issue under stress?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26592826/1945631).

Answer (score 11):

Your code is not thread-safe. `_hashAlgo` cannot be shared between threads. Note that the exception you see is not the only problem that can result; I believe that problem also can lead to incorrect hash values. You need to either create a new `HashAlgorithm` object each time or look into thread locals to create one instance per thread.

Comment: This is most likely the correct answer. See the answer to [Finalizer issue under stress?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26592826/1945631). Concurrent access to instance methods on the same `HashAlgorithm` subclass instance will cause this exception.

Comment: `that problem also can lead to incorrect hash values` -- this is true. I faced and solved same problem some time ago.

Answer (score 2):

The code appears to work fine. The problem could be:

1. Is the object being serialized and deserialized between construction
   and use? If so, move the `MDS.Create()` to inside `GetSignature()`
2. Is the object being disposed (either `SignService` or `_hashAlgo`)?
   If so do not dispose it or recreate it when needed.